# Is there a way to read input directly from the keyboard in standard C++?

Tags: c++, input, console, keyboard

And I know there's `std::cin`, but that requires the user to enter a string, then press ENTER.  Is there a way to simply get the next key that is pushed without needing to press ENTER to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
#include <conio.h>
```

and then catch char with cases such as this

```
char c;
if (_kbhit())
{
  c = getch();
  switch(c)
  {
  case ‘\0H’ :
  cout << "up arrow key!" << endl;
  break;
  }
}
```

**Beware**: I have not tried it... and remember to put the whole thing into a "while(true)" to test.

Comment: I assume that <conio.h> and _kbhit() are windows/DOS specific?

Comment: Also, hoe does '\OH' translate into up arrow? (As in, what are the values of the down, left, and right arrows?)

Comment: @camh: yes, afaik
@Kean64: if i remember correctly, there are constants like  ARROW_KEY_UP, please try that. not in front of my devel computer...

Comment: This is not standard C++

Answer (score 10):

What you're looking for is related to manipulating the console, and is OS-dependent. If you're in a UNIX-based OS, check out the [curses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)), and in Windows, there are `getch()` and `kbhit()` functions from `<conio.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902792/1413395) is a bit outdated.

The [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library (based on the mentioned [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)#ncurses)) is a portable implementation available for unix and linux based operating systems, windows and others.

It supports a wide variety of terminal interfaces.