# C scanning keyboard buffer from inactive window (LINUX)?

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, buffer, daemon

I searched and found this [C - Read Directly From the Keyboard Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322340/c-read-directly-from-the-keyboard-buffer)

What I am trying to do requires an inactive window. I don't know if I need the simplehotkeydeamon to do this or if I can create a service without the deamon. https://github.com/baskerville/shkd

I want to create an ALSA socket (Midi Sound Data) and scan the keyboard buffer without affecting it just looking for shift presses (this doesn't show up as a char) and space button presses.

How do I look at the keyboard buffer without being the active terminal in linux?

Comment: Do you want that on a desktop (that it using [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) ....) or on a native console? What about remote `ssh` connections?

Comment: I am not going to use remote ssh or putty... That would be too much latency... I really want to have the program scan the keyboard interrupt buffer in the background and alter midi code when shift("idk??") or space (" ") is pressed. The program doesn't need to be the active window/terminal. That way I can edit/record the midi in a different app. I am on linux btw.

Comment: I can't Imagine this being too hard... most video games need to scan keyboard input in a similar manner but that is for active windows?? Maybe I would have to use assembly rather than C?